# Deriving new data from Pandas datetime column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've got a column of timestamps (in ms) in a `pandas` DataFrame.  From the timestamps, I'm trying to derive the hour, minute, day of week, and month of the timestamp in separate columns.

I've tried using the `apply` function across the column, but to no avail.  So, I took a very naive (but not very concise) approach to create these columns:

```
import pandas
import datetime

df=pd.DataFrame( {'time':[1401811621559, 1402673694105, 1402673749561, 1401811615479, 1402673708254], 'person':['Harry', 'Ann', 'Sue', 'Jeremy', 'Anne']})

df['time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df.time, unit='ms')
days = []
tod = []
month = []
minutes = []
for row in df['time']:
    days.append(row.strftime('%w'))
    tod.append(row.strftime('%H'))
    month.append(row.strftime('%m'))
    minutes.append(row.strftime('%M'))
##
df['dayOfWeek'] = days
df['timeOfDay'] = tod
df['month'] = month
df['minutes'] = minutes
```

Is there a way to do this that is more like this?

```
df['dayOfWeek'] = df['time'].apply(strftime('%w'),axis = 1)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'strftime' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also make it a lambda function:

```
df['dayOfWeek2'] = df.time.apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%w'))
```

Now typing

```
df.dayOfWeek2 == df.dayOfWeek
```

yields

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks! Works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you have to wrap the column in a DatetimeIndex:

```
In [11]: dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time'])

In [12]: dti.dayofweek
Out[12]: array([1, 4, 4, 1, 4])

In [13]: dti.time
Out[13]:
array([datetime.time(16, 7, 1, 559000), datetime.time(15, 34, 54, 105000),
       datetime.time(15, 35, 49, 561000), datetime.time(16, 6, 55, 479000),
       datetime.time(15, 35, 8, 254000)], dtype=object)

In [14]: dti.month
Out[14]: array([6, 6, 6, 6, 6])

In [15]: dti.minute
Out[15]: array([ 7, 34, 35,  6, 35])
```

etc.

*See [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7207) for making these methods directly available from a datetime series.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, modifying your code slightly...

```
def timeGroups(row):
    row['days'] = row['time'].strftime('%w'))
    #do the same thing for month,seconds,etc.
    return row
df['dayOfWeek'] = df['time'].apply(timeGroups,axis = 1)
```